# Change input value dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change input value and display an alert based on value written by the user. Now it doesn't work unless it goes out of focus. Can I make it work immediately without any waiting period?

```js
jQuery('input').on('change', function () {
    var myInput = jQuery(this);
    if (myInput.val() < 0.2 ) {
        myInput.val('0.2');
        jQuery('.alert').css('display', 'block')
    }
    else {
        jQuery('.alert').css('display', 'none')
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input value="">
<p class="alert" style="display: none">minimum value is 0.2</p>
```

Comment: Use `keyup` instead of `change`. The change event fires when you loose focus of the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.You can use  `input` or `keyup` method.

2.Also `.val()` will give you a string value, so comparing it with 0.2 convert it to float with the help of `parseFloat()`

like below:-

***Example 1:-***

```js
jQuery('input').on('input', function () {
    var myInput = jQuery(this);
    if (parseFloat(myInput.val()) < 0.2 ) {
        jQuery('.alert').css('display', 'block')
    }
    else {
        jQuery('.alert').css('display', 'none')
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input value="">
<p class="alert" style="display: none">minimum value is 0.2</p>
```

***Example 2:-***

```js
jQuery('input').on('keyup', function () {
    var myInput = jQuery(this);
    if (parseFloat(myInput.val()) < 0.2 ) {
        jQuery('.alert').css('display', 'block')
    }
    else {
        jQuery('.alert').css('display', 'none')
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input value="">
<p class="alert" style="display: none">minimum value is 0.2</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do in this case:

1. [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event instead of [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) to "make it work immediately without any waiting period";
2. Add another type of error for the case when your value is an empty or incorrect number.

```js
const $errors = $('.alert');

$('input').on('input', function(e) {
    const $input = $(e.target);
    const value = Number($input.val());
    let errorType = '';
    
    if (!value) {
      errorType = 'required';
    } else if (value < 0.2) {
      errorType = 'min';
      $input.val(0.2);
    }
    
    $errors.addClass('alert_hidden');
    $errors.filter(`[data-type="${errorType}"]`).removeClass('alert_hidden');
});
```

```css
.alert {
  background-color: red;
}

  .alert_hidden {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input value="">
<p class="alert alert_hidden" data-type="min">minimum value is 0.2</p>
<p class="alert alert_hidden" data-type="required">value is required</p>
```